# Adding a setup project in your solution C#

Tags: c#

When creating a setup project in your solution how do you make the setup to check if the appropriate .Net Framework is installed on the PC you are installing your application

Comment: Visual Studio 2003 through Visual Studio 2010 has this feature built into it.  I have no idea what versions of Visual Studio of an indivual release had this feature, but the feature itself is no longer supported, and your better off using a third-party program to create a setup executable anyways.  There are free solutions, of course, you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi) explaining this. The article might seem outdated, but the idea and the location remains the same.

Basically, there are options in your setup project properties to select which prerequisites to install and to add custom ones.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Setup engine.  If you are using InstallShield LE then there is an option in the redistributables (or mebe dependancies) section.